# When @react-navigation with fullScreenGestureEnabled = true, partial "empty" header background shown between screen transition

Tags: react-native, darkmode, react-navigation-v6

I'm using `@react-navigation`, combining NativeStackNavigator and BottomTabNavigator.

A "white" background shown in dark mode when `fullScreenGestureEnabled=true`.  I want to know if there is any workaround to handle this situation.

[image: screen-transition]

demo `App.js`

```js
import { DarkTheme, NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function HomeScreen(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          props.navigation.push('Detail')
        }}
      >
      <Text> Go to detail</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  )
}

function Screen(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{props.route.name}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

function MainTabs(props) {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Screen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
function AppStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        fullScreenGestureEnabled: true,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainTabs}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={Screen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Screen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings Detail" component={Screen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={DarkTheme}>
      <StatusBar style='inverted' />
      <AppStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#444444',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I have tried hiding header of screens inside tab navigator, preserving the outer tab header, but does not find a way to handle the `title` text update.

Answer (score 0):

Stack header animation is done from multiple headers from `Stack.Screen`s and not from all general headers.

As `Main` screen doesn't have stack header, You are seeing that blank white background.

You should make `Main` page header shown to get proper stack animation or remove all headers in `Stack.Navigator` and manually create header on each pages.